# Overlaid histograms in R (ggplot2 preferred)

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, histogram

I am trying to create a layered histogram like this with ggplot2:
[image: Style plot that I'd like to create]

Here are some data and code that I thought would work:

```
my.data <- data.frame(treat = rep(c(0, 1), 100), prop_score = runif(2 * 100))
my.data <- transform(my.data, treat = ifelse(treat == 1, "treatment", "control"))
my.data <- transform(my.data, treat = as.factor(treat))
my.fig <- ggplot() + geom_histogram(data = my.data, binwidth = 0.05, alpha = 0.01, aes(x = prop_score, linetype = treat, position = identity))
```

But my code produces this:
[image]

Thanks! I would prefer `ggplot2` (while I'm learning, I figured I just learn the common, extensible plotting language), but I'm open to anything/everything.

Comment: Since treat is numeric, you either need to change it to a factor or specify `group = treat`.

Comment: @Hadley -- Thanks! I fixed my factor gross conceptual error, but I am missing some other concepts. I tried `alpha = 0` but that removed the lines, too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

[image: Overlaid histograms]

Note that I changed your treatment indicator variable to be `TRUE/FALSE` rather than `0/1`, since it needs to be a factor for ggplot to split on it. The `scale_alpha` is a bit of a hack because it's for continuous variables, but there isn't a discrete analogue as far as I can tell.

```
library('ggplot2')
my.data <- data.frame(treat = rep(c(FALSE, TRUE), 100), prop_score = runif(2 * 100))
ggplot(my.data) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.05
                 , aes(  x = prop_score
                       , alpha = treat
                       , linetype = treat)
                 , colour="black"
                 , fill="white"
                 , position="stack") +
  scale_alpha(limits = c(1, 0))
```

Comment: Thanks! With `identity` I was trying to get them properly overlaid. Is that possible? If the counts are the same, then the lines will overlap, but that's OK with me.

Comment: richard, yes, you can use `position="identity"`. I must have just mentally changed it when making the plot.

Answer (score 2):

FWIW, I built on the answers above the get really close to the original histogram I provided.

```
data.3.t <- subset(data.3, treat == 1)
data.3.c <- subset(data.3, treat == 0)

fig.3 <- ggplot()
fig.3 <- fig.3 + geom_histogram(data = data.3.t , binwidth = 0.05, aes(x = prop_score, linetype = treat.factor), fill = NA, colour = "black")
fig.3 <- fig.3 + geom_histogram(data = data.3.c, binwidth = 0.05, aes(x = prop_score, linetype = treat.factor), fill = NA, colour = "black")
fig.3 <- fig.3 + scale_linetype_manual(values = c(1,2))
fig.3 <- fig.3 + labs(x = "propensity score", linetype = "group")
fig.3 <- fig.3 + theme_bw()
```

Which gives something like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
my.fig <- ggplot(data = my.data) + 
          geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.05,
                         aes(x = prop_score,
                             position = identity,
                             linetype=treat),
                         fill="white", 
                         colour="black",alpha=0)+
          scale_linetype_manual(values=c(1,2))+
          theme_bw()
```

Comment: I think you probably want `fill = NA`

Comment: & Hadley -- Yes, the `fill = NA` does the trick. But I'd still like to get them "overlaid". This would make same counts in the same bin plot one on top the other, but that's OK with me. Is that possible?

Comment: Ok. It doesn't make sense to set fill when alpha=0, so it can be omitted.